# Oracle SELECT statement not working - ORA-00942

Tags: php, oracle, ora-00942

Hopefully a simple question.

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $c = oci_connect('whatmyusrnameis', 'whatmypwdis', 'host');
    if ($c) {
            echo 'connection';

    }
    $s = oci_parse($c, 'select *  from mantis_bug_table');
    oci_execute($s);
```

The following results in

Warning `oci_execute(): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

but the connection doesn't result in any errors and the DB table does exist and it is not empty.

Any ideas???  Thank you :).

Comment: Is the table in the schema that you are accessing (you may need to fully qualify it) or does it have a synonym?

Comment: Do you use EBS (Entreprise Business Suite ) ? If ye, you may have to set your session to be able to see some tables/views/datas...

Comment: VOTE TO CLOSE PLEASE :)... MY ORACLE HAD SHORTERNED MY TABLE NAMES WITHOUT ME KNOWING!  mantis_bug_table was m_bug_t :S

Comment: I don't think Oracle would have arbitrarily shortened your table name... More likely your DBA gave you a synonym that was shorter or someone else changed your table name.

Comment: @alemaster IMHO just because one of the assumptions in your question was incorrect doesn't necessarily mean that it should be closed. Someone may have the same assumption and I believe that my answer and Justin's covers that. Furthermore someone may choose this question in the future to give the canonical answer for ORA-00942. See [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: Hi sorry for the caps in the above post.. I was exhausted when I wrote it.  I meant that my DBA had shorterned them without me knowing.. you guessed correctly :p.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically this has one of four possible problems

1. You're not connecting to the database you think you are (probably not the case)
2. You don't have permission to the table (See Justin Cave's answer regarding Grant)
3. You may need to add the owner to the table name e.g. `select *  from DB_USER.mantis_bug_table` (See Justin Cave's answer regarding SYNONYMs if you don't want qualify the tablename)
4. The table really doesn't exist perhaps a spelling error

You can diagnose this by running the following

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE UPPER(table_name) = 'MANTIS_BUG_TABLE'
```

Comment: Thanks.. With this query you gave me I get: IRA-00904 "mantis_user_table": invalid identifer

Comment: hmm where are you executing the query?

Comment: Note that unless the table was created as `"mantis_bug_table"` (ie: case-sensitive), you'll have to use uppercase names when querying the `ALL_TABLES` view.

Comment: @NullUserException, technically it depends on the Linguistic Sort Parameters, but your point is taken.

Comment: @Conrad Ah, that's true. But most installations are case-sensitive by default.

Comment: Accepting because it was a nice answer even though my solution was different :).

Comment: I was facing case of *#3* :)

Answer (score 3):

- What Oracle user owns the table?
- Does the Oracle user that your PHP script connects as have access to this table?
- Is there a public or private synonym for the `MANTIS_BUG_TABLE` table?

If the table is owned by some other user, you could try fully qualifying the table name

```
$s = oci_parse($c, 'select *  from owner_of_table.mantis_bug_table');
```

If the user your PHP script is using doesn't have access to the table, you'll need a DBA or the owner of the table to

```
GRANT SELECT ON owner_of_table.mantis_bug_table
   TO whatmyusernameis;
```

If you have access to the table and fully qualifying the table name works but you don't want to have to fully qualify the table name every time, you can create a synonym

```
CREATE [PUBLIC] SYNONYM mantis_bug_table
   FOR owner_of_table.mantis_bug_table
```

A public synonym allows all users with access to the table to reference it without using a fully qualified name.  A private synonym allows just the owner of the synonym (i.e. whatmyusernameis) to reference the table without a fully qualified table name.

Answer (score -1):

You should point scheme in connection string like:

```
oci_connect('whatmyusrnameis', 'whatmypwdis', 'host/**YOUR_DB**');
```

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php in section **connection_string**

Comment: -1 He/she wouldn't get this far if they were unable to connect.